# Jquery undefined при попытке вывести строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такая проблема.

Есть калькулятор который считает стоимость допустим.

```
<div class="items">

    <div class="item">

        <div class="item_name">NAME</div>
        <div class="item_price">2000</div>
        <div class="item_count">
            <input type="text" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="item_endprice">0</div>

    </div>

    <div class="item">

        <div class="item_name">NAME</div>
        <div class="item_price">2000</div>
        <div class="item_count">
            <input type="text" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="item_endprice">0</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Значит что необходимо: Есть 4 поля
item_name - Имя услуги
item_price - Цена
item_count - это поле содержащее изменяемый input (количество)
item_endprice - итоговая цена которая высчитывается

И так начинаю писать сам скрипт

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('.items').delegate('.item_count input', 'change', function () {
        calculate(this);
    });
    jQuery('.items').delegate('.item_count input', 'keyup', function () {
        calculate(this);
    });

    // Получается что я обьявил, как только происходит изменение в input то мы начинаем считать, далее пишу функцию калькулятора

    function calculate(e) {
        price = parseFloat(jQuery(e).parent().prev('.item_input').html());
        name = jQuery(e).parent().prev('.item_name').html();

        count = parseFloat(jQuery(e).val());
        if (isNaN(count)) {
            count = 0;
        }
        endprice = price * count;

        jQuery(e).parent().next('.item_total').html(endprice);

        //И вывожу расчеты в консоль

        console.log(name);
        console.log(price);
        console.log(count);
        console.log(endprice);

    }
});
```

Так вот вся проблема в том, что все выводится правильно кроме name.
name выводит undefined, я все никак не могу понять почему

Версия jQuery :1.10.2

Comment: какая версия jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам посоветовал обращаться к элементам так:

```
var prnt=$(this).closest('.item');
var name=prnt.find('.item_name').html();
var price=prnt.find('.item_price').html();
var count=prnt.find('.item_count input').val();
var endprice=prnt.find('.item_endprice').html();
```

А ошибка у вас из-за того, что

```
name = jQuery(e).parent().prev()
```

возвращает предыдущие элемент, у вас это ***.item_price***, а вы пытаетесь выбрать ***.item_name***

Что бы заработал ваш код, напишите так

```
name = jQuery(e).parent().siblings('.item_name').html();
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему - потому что Вы неправильно понимаете что делает [вызов prev() с параметром](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Вы ожидаете что `element.prev(selector)` проверяет **все** предыдущие элементы на соответствие селектору и **находит** тот, который селектору соответствует, если он есть.

На самом деле `element.prev(selector)` проверяет **один** предыдущий элемент на соответствие селектору и возвращает **пустую выборку**, в случае несоответствия этого одного элемента.

Проще всего, если сохранять вашу логику, использовать [`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/), вернув все предыдущие элменты и отфильтровав их например селектором `:first`. (Это не особо быстро, но у вас не такой скрипт чтобы это играло роль).
Вообще логику поиска этого элемента можно организовать и по-другому, как предложили Igor и Diefair

Добавлю, что объявляя переменные без `var` Вы объявляете глобальные переменные. 
**Не надо так, это очень плохо.**

Для вашего кода можно так:

```
var name = jQuery(e).parent().prevAll('.item_name:first').html();
```

Comment: или `var name = jQuery(e).closest(".item").find('.item_name').html();`

Comment: @Igor, ага, или так)